# Object Parenting in Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Lets say that I create three (3) cubes, side by side, in Geometry Nodes. Now, I want to make the center cube parent to the others. Is this possible? I am not seeing an option to parent in Geometry Nodes.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this kind of node setup:

[image]

I used these "legs" with the pivot points as you can see here:

[image]

The Sub leg is the child of the Main leg (no, don't set this in relation, the node tree behaves like this would be the case).

How it works? i set the boolean attribute to True for the Sub leg. Via the join geometry i can move both objects via the transform geometry node which "looks like" that i move the parent object (main leg). Now i can separate the geometry via that Sub attribute and rotate (rotate instances) just the child object via rotate instances node. Of course i have to join afterwards both objects.

result:

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution, as nested instances can't be accessed (e.g. rotated), only the outer layer (parent) can.

Answer (score 1):

Geometry Nodes is a modifier. This means it works on a single object. It is not meant to control the 3d scene and object hierarchy so you cannot do object parenting in Geometry Nodes. You could probably replicate various kinds of functionality similar to parenting with Geometry Nodes, but you certainly cannot change object hierarchy in the scene from the modifier.

Comment: That much I understand. Yet, with all the "instances" of objects are created, there should be a means of establishing relationships between those objects.

Comment: What are you talking about? Instances created with geometry nodes remain in a single object, don't they?

Comment: Let's take the example you provided with 3 cubes. Let's see how that would go. [Here it is](https://i.imgur.com/xNAW4rp.png) What objects do you want to have what relationships in this case? There is only one object.

Comment: Even more so, a modifier (I think each modifier) can only access the data of the object (a mesh, or curve data), it can't even modify the properties of an object like its scale for example. Though I'm not sure, e.g. attributes reside on object wrapper rather than mesh data? Since geonodes can create attributes, so perhaps they have some access to the object…

Comment: Can you modify transforms of an object from modifier without Python? I don't think so... I don't think the devs would implement something like that because that would conflict with other features(keyframes, drivers and so on)